# “Fun with Rotation” - Codechef September Long Challenge

Tags: c

Whatz wrong with that answer?Plz help me

question is:
You are given an array A of N integers. You are to fulfill M queries. Each query has one of the following three types:
C d : Rotate the array A clockwise by d units.
A d : Rotate the array A anticlockwise by d units.
R d : Query for the value of the element, currently being the d-th in the array A.
Input

The first line contains two numbers - N and M respectively.
The next line contains N space separated Integers, denoting the array A.
Each of the following M lines contains a query in the one of the forms described above.
Output

For each query of type R output the answer on a separate line.
Constraints

1 ≤ N ≤ 100000
1 ≤ M ≤ 100000
1 ≤ d ≤ N, in all the queries
1 ≤ elements of A ≤ 1000000
The array A and the queries of the type R are 1-based.

Example

Input:
5 5
5 4 3 3 9
R 1
C 4
R 5
A 3
R 2
Output:
5
3
3

Solution:

```
#include<stdio.h>
//#include<iostream>
//using namespace std;
int a[100001];
int index=0,n;

void clock(int);
void ant_clock(int);
void display(int);

int main()
{
    unsigned int i,m;
    char x;
    int y;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    while(m--)
    {
        scanf(" %c%d",&x,&y);
        if(1 <= y <= n)
        {
            if(x=='R')
                display(y);
            else if(x=='A')
                ant_clock(y);
            else if(x=='C')
                clock(y);
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

void display(int y)
{
    int j=index,x=0;
    while(1)
    {
        if(x==y-1)
            break;
        j++;
        x++;
        if(j==n)
            j=0;
    }
    printf("%d",a[j]);
}

void ant_clock(int y)
{
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<y;j++)
    {
        index--;
        if(index==-1)
            index=n-1;
    }
}

void clock(int y)
{
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<y;j++)
    {
        index++;
        if(index==n)
            index=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with the query indices being 1-based. And your code has unnecessary loops in it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arr[100000];

int main() {
    int base = 0, size, i, m;
    char x;
    scanf("%d%d", &size, &m);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    while (m-- > 0) {
        scanf(" %c%d", &x, &i);
        if (x == 'R') {
            printf("%d\n", arr[(base + i - 1) % size]);
        } else if (x == 'A') {
            if ((base -= i) < 0)
                base += size;
        } else if (x == 'C') {
            base = (base + i) % size;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```